# How to generate 4-4-5 retail calendar in Dbt / Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am using DBT, I need to generate a 4-4-5 calendar for year 2021 to year 2025 to join with my weekly data drop. Is there a way to write sql (with macro if necessary), or import some package to generate 4-4-5 retail calendars in dbt?

Comment: Generating a standard calendar procedurally, while doable, is probably way more work and way more error prone than just finding a public one that goes back to the dawn of time and out to the foreseeable future. Then loading it as a static table. Have you seen this in the Snowflake Marketplace? https://app.snowflake.com/marketplace/listing/GZSNZ2FNMS/mondo-analytics-calendars-for-finance-and-analytics

Comment: When I googled this the third entry was a step by step guide to generating this type of calendar with dbt

Comment: @NickW that really is a nice and detailed post explaining it.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I was making the point that it’s probably worth spending at least some effort researching a problem before posting a question on this forum

Answer (score 1):

My favorite answer from the comments is using the data already available in the Snowflake Marketplace. Moving the answer here for completitude:

```sql
select *
from CALENDARS_FOR_FINANCE_AND_ANALYTICS.PUBLIC.V_CALENDAR_445
order by date_at desc
limit 100
```

- https://app.snowflake.com/marketplace/listing/GZSNZ2FNMS/mondo-analytics-calendars-for-finance-and-analytics

Has rows until 2026.

For generating these rows with dbt I would look at the following dbt package, modifying their 4-5-4 logic to 4-4-5:

- https://github.com/calogica/dbt-date/blob/main/macros/fiscal_date/get_fiscal_periods.sql